# Jquery Accordion open with select drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have two functions for select drop down menus, and a function for a accordion to animate when I click a title. I also want the accordion to animate when one of the options have been selected from the drop down menu.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

    // expand or collapse this panel
    $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');

    // hide the other panels
    $('.accordion-content').not($(this).next()).slideUp('slow');

});

    $('#size').change(function(){ 
        if ($(this).val() > 0 )  { 
              $('#pizza').addClass('pizzaImage');
         }  
    });

    $('#crust').change(function(){ 
        if ($(this).val() > 0 ) { 
              $('#pizza').addClass('pizzaImage');
         }      
    });

});
```

what do I have to do to open the accordion not with a click but when a option is selected from the drop down menu?